# PubNub Node util.inherit is not a function

Tags: javascript, pubnub

After adding the pubnub node sdk to my nativescript Project

`npm install pubnub`

I get following error message:

```
> System.err: Error: Parsing XML at 58:9 System.err:  > util.inherits is
> not a function
```

I simply require it like this:

```
const PubNub = require("pubnub");
```

Any idea how that could happen?

Comment: Usage of util.inherits() is discouraged. use the ES6 class and extends

Comment: @Endless I Comes from a library I am not using it directly

Comment: Currently, PubNub Node SDK is not compatible with NativeScript v5. It is compatible with NativeScript v3.

PubNub is investigating changes that can be made to be compatible with NativeScript v5.

Comment: @Jonnotdoexx - You provided a workaround that provides compatibility. Please provide your solution as an official answer to your question and you will earn additional Stack Overflow rep.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, PubNub Node SDK is not compatible with NativeScript v5. It is compatible with NativeScript v3. PubNub is investigating changes that can be made to be compatible with NativeScript v5.

Workaround by @Jon_not_doe_xx:

In the `webpack.config.js` file, add this in the head:

```js
const shims = require('nativescript-nodeify/shims.json');
const aliases = {};

for (const key of Object.keys(shims)) {
    const value = shims[key];
    aliases[key + '$'] = value;
}

aliases['inherits$'] = 'inherits/inherits_browser';

// Remove hook, as this will only cause problems at this point.
// Checking and deleting within webpack ensures 
//   that it will be deleted during a cloud build.

let fs = require("fs");
let process = require("process");

if (fs.existsSync(__dirname + "/hooks/after-prepare/nativescript-nodeify.js")) {
    process.stdout.write("Found evil hook, deleting...\n");
    fs.unlinkSync(__dirname + "/hooks/after-prepare/nativescript-nodeify.js");
    process.stdout.write("Should be fixed now.\n");
}

else process.stdout.write("Hooks seem clean, moving on.\n");
```

Also, modify the alias object inside the resolve object in the `webpack.config.js` file:

```js
alias: {
    '~': appFullPath,
    '@': appFullPath,
    ...aliases 
},
```